# Input into array only if form field is not empty

Tags: arrays, mongodb, forms, express, ejs

I am trying to edit a db item on MongoDB using mongoose and express/ejs. I got the edit form working where I can add new entries into the array properly but having trouble with empty input fields being added to the array on submission. Could someone recommend a good way to create the edit form where empty input fields will not be submitted?

```
<div class="uk-margin">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-horizontal-text">Tag</label>
    <% project.tag.forEach(function(i, el) { %>
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <input class="uk-input" type="text" name="project[tag][<%= el %>]" value="<%= project.tag[el] %>">
        </div>
    <% });%>
    <input class="uk-input" type="text" name="project[tag][<%= project.tag.length %>]" placeholder="project[tag][<%= project.tag.length %>]">
</div>
```

What happens is when I submit the form, the empty input field will add a new entry into the array.

```
// before form submission
project.tag
   [0] HTML
   [1] CSS

//after form submission
project.tag
   [0] HTML
   [1] CSS
   [2]
```